# check if the value is phone number in model sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How can I add validation for value in model to accept only mobile number form cutom country
I just did that but I don't what should do next

user will enter the phone number like that "+15555555555"

```
phone: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notNull: { args: true, msg: "You must enter Phone Number" },
      len: { args: [11,11], msg: 'Phone Number is invalid' },
      isInt: { args: true, msg: "You must enter Phone Number" },
    }
  },
```

Comment: What's a phone number? And that's a real question: the "+country code, and then 10 digits" is not true for every country. Also, what are you validating? User input, or sanitized user input? (e.g. would you be storing "+1-555-555-5555" ? What about "+1 555 5555555"? Maybe "+15555555555"? Your post might need a few more details)

Comment: I just edit the question thanx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to validate phone number pattern of specific country:

```js
//regex that validate phone pattern for specific country
const phoneValidationRegex = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/ 
phone: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
        validator: function(v) {
            return phoneValidationRegex.test(v); 
        },
    }
}
```